# How to use Union All and GROUP BY when combining multiple #Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I need to UNION ALL multiple temptables and each have to be sorted by YearNum DESC.

```
    ;WITH cte_yoyComparison
AS
            (
SELECT      b.YearNum, 
            --b.MonthNum,
            b.MonthName,
            sum(Premium) as Premium 
            FROM tblCalendar b  
LEFT JOIN Test_Plaza_ProductionReport  a ON b.MonthNum=MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate) <> 2017
GROUP BY    b.YearNum, 
            --b.MonthNum,
            b.MonthName
            )


select [YearNum] as [YearNum],
[January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December] into #TempData from ( select * from cte_yoyComparison) src
PIVOT
    (
            sum(src.Premium)
            FOR src.[MonthName] IN ([January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December])
    ) as [PivotTable]
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempData1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempData1
;WITH cte_yoyComparison
AS
        (
SELECT  b.YearNum,
        --b.MonthNum, 
        b.MonthName,
        ISNULL(sum(case when TransactionType IN ('Policy', 'Reinstatement') then 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as Bound--,   
FROM    tblCalendar b  LEFT JOIN Test_Plaza_ProductionReport  a ON b.MonthNum=MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
WHERE YEAR(EffectiveDate) <> 2017
GROUP BY    b.YearNum, 
            b.MonthName,
            b.MonthNum
            )
select [YearNum] as [YearNum], 
[January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December] into #TempData1 from ( select * from cte_yoyComparison) src
PIVOT
    (
            sum(Bound)
            FOR src.[MonthName] IN ([January], [February],[March], [April],[May],[June],[July], [August], [September],[October],[November],[December])
    ) as [PivotTable]
    order by YearNum DESC 

select * from #TempData
union all
select * from #TempData1
```

The result of it looks like that:[image]

But I need it like that:
[image]

I tried to add RowNumber to each of the CTE but still no luck.

Comment: So the data is OK, only the order is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First note this kind of things usually are handle on the UI not in db*.

But this may solve your problem

```
SELECT *  -- or put the fieldList without the *sortfield*
FROM (
       select '1' sortField, * from #TempData
       union all
       select '2' sortField, * from #TempData1
     ) T
ORDER BY sortField, YearField DESC
```

Comment: Why add `sortField` to the `ORDER BY`? Won't that give the same results?

Comment: @bjones No ... if you not include the sortField, you will get the year rows side by side. This groupt each table result in a separated group.

Comment: I see. I think I was confused by the question.

Comment: Thanks Juan. It works. I am using SSRS, you saying I can achieve same result in it?